# Scrolldown to footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone know how to automatically scroll down to footer section when a specified `div` clicked using jquery ?

Comment: actually you should do more research before asking ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: here is an example of what you are looking for http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/01/03/scrolling-to-the-top-and-bottom-with-jquery/

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop(99999);` 99999 or a high value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it  by [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) by giving id to your footer section, check the [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$('#clickableItem').bind('click', function () {
  // get the distence left and top from the document left and top sides
  var _offset = $('#footer').offset(); 
  $(window).scrollTop(_offset.top);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("body").height()` will calculate the height of the window
and if you assign the height value to the scrollTop attribute of your html/body job is done

```
$('html, body').scrollTop($("body").height());
```